# Zenity form from hell

Tags: bash, sh, zenity

This *editable zenity form* is filled with info gathered from a file ( called ip.txt) and shown to the user.

If the user makes a change to the form ( t.ex changing the ip to 10.0.0.100 instead of what is stated in the form ) **i want to save those changes to a new file called newip.txt**.

For clarification check the printscreen of the form itself

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9LHuquISrCmR3BDTnl5WXlqSVU/view?usp=sharing

```
grep -Eo "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}" /home/user/Desktop/ip.txt >>  ip.bak
ip=$(sed -n 3p  /home/user/Desktop/ip.bak )
mask=$(sed -n 2p /home/user/Desktop/ip.bak)
gateway=$(sed -n 3p  /home/user/Desktop/ip.bak)
dns=$(sed -n 4p  /home/user/Desktop/ip.bak)
actip=$(sudo ifconfig eth1 | grep "inet " | awk -F'[: ]+' '{ print $4 }')
gtw=$(ip route list | sed -n -e "s/^default.*[[:space:]]\([[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\.[[:digit:]]\+\).*/\1/p")

selection=$(zenity --list --height=350 --width=450  --editable --hide-column=1 \
  --title="Active IP - $aktip | Gateway - $gtw " \
  --column="" --column="Ändra om det behövs" --column="Adresser" \
    2 "IP-address from file" "$ip" \
    3 "Mask-address from file" "$mask" \
    4 "Gateway-address from file " "$gateway" \
    5 "Dns i file" "$dns"  \))


case "$selection" in
"2")zenity --info --text="some command" ;;
"3")zenity --info --text="some command";;
"4")zenity --info --text="some command";;
"5")zenity --info --text="some command";;
"6")zenity --info --text="some command";;
esac
```

Comment: ps since the system is an industrial system.. i can not install _yad_ .. so i need to make the best of what i´ve got.. that is zenity ^^

Comment: An industrial system that uses `bash` instead of a proper general-purpose programming language?

Comment: its only a one time setup for a few  configuration files from usb memory stick ( static ip address and addon for firefox ) made by a tehnician with limited experience.